# Laravel 5.4 master blade: show data from database in footer

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

I have created a master.blade.php file as follow:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    @include('layouts.head_files')
  </head>

  <body>

        <!-- START MAIN WRAPPER -->
        <div id="wrapper">

        <!-- SEARCH FORM START -->  
            @yield('info_panel')
        <!-- SEARCH FORM END -->


        <!-- Start Page Content -->
        <div class="recent-job">
            <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">                     
                @yield('main_content')                                          
                <div class="spacer-2"></div>
                </div>      
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Page Content -->

    </div>
        <!-- END MAIN WRAPPER -->

   @include('layouts.footer_files')
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my footer_file.blade.php file

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
     $('input.location').typeahead({
        name: 'location',
        local: ['London','Birmingham','Manchester', 'Liverpool']
     });
     });  
     </script>

<script src="<?=asset('assets');?>/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?=asset('assets');?>/js/jquery.easytabs.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?=asset('assets');?>/js/modernizr.custom.49511.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="<?=asset('assets');?>/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="<?=asset('assets');?>/js/typeheads.min.js"></script>
```

As you can see I have an array of some cities in a function in my footer_file files. I have hard coded it for now but I want to fetch the list of all cities from database and show it here. This footer is included in every page. I am finding it difficult to do it in Laravel. It was easy in Codeigniter. Can I access the database directly from my view? Please help.

Comment: check this it might help you https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#view-composers

Answer (score 2):

> Occasionally, you may need to share a piece of data with all views that are rendered by your application. You may do so using the view facade's share method. Typically, you should place calls to share within a service provider's boot method. You are free to add them to the AppServiceProvider or generate a separate service provider to house them.

```
public function boot()
{
    $data = App\Model::get();
    View::share('data', $data);
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#sharing-data-with-all-views

Alternative to this solution is using [view composer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#view-composers):

```
View::composer('layouts.footer_files', function ($view) {
    ....
});
```